# What is $\sup_n f_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

Let $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of measurable functions on $\mathbb R^d$. What is the significance of $\sup_n f_n$ ? Is it $$\sup\{f_n(x)\mid n\in\mathbb N, x\in \mathbb R^d\}\ \ ?$$

Comment: $x$ is fixed. The supremum is taken in $n$ over all $f_n(x)$.

Comment: It's a number for each value of $x$, which makes it a function of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's the function defined for all $x$ by
$$(\sup_n f_n)(x)=\sup_n\bigl\{f_n(x)\bigr\}.$$

As an illuminating example, for $2$ functions $f$ and $g$, $\;(\sup\{f,g\})(x)$ is $f(x)$ when $f(x)\ge g(x)$ and $g(x)$ when $f(x)<g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an example that may explain it. Let  $$f_n(x)=1-x^n, \quad 0\le x\le 1$$ Then $$\sup_nf_n(0)=1$$ (this is also a $\max$ because it is attained, because sometimes $\sup$ causes confusion) and by taking the limit $n \to \infty$ for *any fixed $x \in (0,1)$* $$\sup_nf_n(x)=1$$ (this is indeed a $\sup$ because the value $1$ is actually never attained but is indeed the least upper bound). But $$\sup_nf_n(1)=0$$